# Does .live() need a selector to start with?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery as so

```
$('.mybutton').live('click', function(){
   // do something
});
```

this is called when the document is ready but when the document is ready there are 'mybutton' classes being used, but if the user clicks somewhere a new form appears which uses the button with the class 'mybutton'. But this does not seem to be working, and it doesn't have the required handler.

Is this because there where no 'mybutton' classes to start with on the document ready?

Comment: $().live should not depend on the presence or otherwise of elements matching the selector.  This means that your problem is probably somewhere in  your implementation.  Could you post your code/a link to your code?

Comment: You can use `live` outsite document ready. It adds an event listener on the window that checks your jQuery selector everytime you fire the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `live()` ever doesn't seem to work for an element that has the proper selector, like `.mybutton` in your case, it is likely because some ancestor element of the `.mybutton` is preventing bubbling from happening.

If *any* ancestor of a `.mybutton` has:

```
return false;
```

or:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

This will effectively disable `.live()` for that `.mybutton` because `.live()` needs the event to bubble all the way up to the root.

Comment: @Jas - Good catch. Thanks for correcting my spelling flub. :o)

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem, sorry for not accepting the answer earlier, internet problems see :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: okay, i miunderstood your question.
This is more an answer to "Is a selector always required with `live()`?".

---

Yes.
See the caveats section on this [wiki page](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

The reason why a selector is required with jquery.live() is [explained here](http://www.neeraj.name/2009/10/14/how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery.html).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this instead:

```
$('#myForm').delegate('.mybutton', 'click', function() {
   // do something.
})
```